# Magento : Need a to change position of right side navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, navigation

I have to change in right navigation categories , price filter and Popular tags positions.

[image]

As you show in Image I want change of popular tags(1) first to last means in last after top Rated Product(5) .

Ans just want to change 2-3 section position means First I want Filter By Price and Then after Categories.

I also use **AFTER** and **BEFORE** in XML file but is not woring.

Let me now proper and best way to set it.

Comment: above screenshot is your current situation and you want to achieve 3-2-4-1-5 right?

Comment: @gopal no Right is  3-2-4-5-1

Comment: please provide your xml for reference

Comment: I had changed all in different file

Comment: without your xml reference we can not able to help you. Because by default in magento keeps navigation block in `left_first` but here its in middle. May Be theme has changed the structure. that's why you have to provide layout file

Comment: There is around 20 file and all code is in different file. This is not in left side I have set it all in Right side.<reference name="right">

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to move some blocks to the right and keep the rest in the left, you have to change a template from `2columns-left.phtml` to `3columns.phtml` to have 1column in right and 1column in left then you put your blocks there.

To change the template:

```
<your_layout_handle>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
</your_layout_handle>
```

Then you can use:

```
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <block>block.name</block> 
    </action>
</reference>

<reference name="left">
    <action method="insert">
        <block>block.name</block>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Sorry but not working